# Twitter API Tweet Location

Tags: javascript, twitter

I can easily get the tweet text and user info using:

```
var tweet = data.statuses[index];
tweet.text, tweet.user.screen_name etc
```

however I cannot seem to get the location information for the tweet (ie where it was sent from). It always seems to be null?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to exactly this problem is the following logic:

```
    function setLocation(tweet){
        var location = null;

        // Try coordinates first, as it gives the most concrete data.
        if (tweet.coordinates) {
            location = (tweet.coordinates.coordinates).toString();
        }
        // Next up, try tweet.place, which could also have a full street address, and will have at least the full_name and country, if not null 
         else if (tweet.place) {
            var street = "";
            if (tweet.place.attributes.street_address){
                street += tweet.place.attributes.street_address + ", ";
                if (tweet.place.attributes['623:id']){
                    street += tweet.place.attributes['623:id'] + ", "; 
                }
            } 
            location = street + tweet.place.full_name + ", " + tweet.place.country;
        // Lastly, if all else fails, grab the user location. This data is pretty poor, but is at least something. You may not want it, depending on your usage.
        } else if (tweet.user && tweet.user.location){
            location = tweet.user.location;         
        } 
        return location;
    }
```

In that logic, I'm looking at three different places for usable locations: `tweet.coordinates`, `tweet.place` and its subfields, and `tweet.user.location`. All of these fields *may be* present in a complete, JSON-formatted tweet, but Twitter is very explicit that they *are not necessarily* there. Hence, I have all the `if` statements checking for existence of the fields/values.

Still, about 1/3rd to 1/2 of the time, there simply isn't any location data on a tweet. There's nothing you can do about that, and in the above code, you'll get a null return if there is no location. If your logic demands that you absolutely have to have location data for *every* tweet, you can put `&geocode=true` in your query string. That'll cause Twitter to filter out non-located tweets in their response. I haven't used this myself, so can't vouch for how well it does this. Very few tweets (I'd estimate less than 1%, based on my experience with the above function) have geocoding enabled, so using `geocode=true` may cut down the volume of your response data considerably.

A disclaimer: I prioritize `tweet.coordinates` in my code, and then keep checking for the field which will provide the next most reliable data, till I get to `tweet.user.location`, which is whatever the user has listed on their profile. This may be anything. It will occasionally give you something like "In Outer $paaaaaaace' -- which is, presumably, not accurate, and is definitely not helpful for most apps. So, buyer beware, with `user.location`; it works fine for my process, but you may need to apply stricter limits to satisfy your logic.

Lastly, a clarifier: I concatenate strings as I go, and return location as a string. This is for compatibility, as I'm not sure if I'll find coordinates (and object with 'coordinates' and 'type' properites) or one of the other options. Again, variance is large from one tweet to the next. You can't always count on the same data being returned and need to make provisions for weird stuff, or no stuff at all, coming in the tweet.

Refer to [this](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets) for more details about what's in a tweet. It'll really help to clarify from where location could be grabbed. Here's another site that details tweet [places.](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/places)